# Loop over a table then use a function to retrieve the data then insert each row to another table

Tags: postgresql

Table has data like this

```
2302    20201124-000000000024
2302    20201124-000000000025
2302    20201124-000000000026
2302    20201124-000000000027
```

Loop through the table with the data with two columns listed above

```
insert into trade_invoice ( clientid, clientname, invoicedate, amount )
from
select * generate_invoice(2302, '20201124-000000000024') 

end loop
```

Comment: What does `generate_invoice()` return?

Comment: The generate_invoice will fetch the clientid, clientname, invoicedate, amount data.

Comment: So what exactly is the return type of that function?

Comment: Generally one avoids looping in SQL. Where is the beginning of the loop? What are you looping over? What is the name of the table with the data? What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: invoice_tracker is the name of the table.

Comment: The function returns a table query RETURN query
(
SELECT  user_id         as "ClientID",
        trade_date      as "TradeDate",
        cl_ordid        as "ClientOrderID",
        case when side = '1'
                then
                        0.00::numeric(20,2) 
                else
                        stock_trans_amt::numeric(20,2)
        end as "SalesTax" ,
        total_cost::numeric(20,2)      as "NetAmount"
FROM stock_portfolio_details 
WHERE   user_id = userid
  AND trade_matchid = refnum
)
;